# Which is the most similar NP classic problem, if any exists, to this one?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, combinatorics, np-hard, np

Consider a given set $W = \{w_1, w_2,...,w_N\}$ of weights, such that $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i = 0$. Consider the given set of mutually different elements $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_M\}$ with $M\leq N$. Consider the set $S$ as a length-N sequence in which all elements of $A$ appear (therefore some $a_i$ can be repeated).

Define the set  $G_{j} = \{k: s_k = a_j\}$ as the collection of positions within $S$ of element $a_j$ $\, j=1,...,M$. Similarly, $W_j = \{w_k \;\textrm{for } k \in G_j\}$.

Find all arrangements $S$ such that the sum of elements in $W_j$ is zero $\forall j=1,...,M$.

For example, for
$W=\{ -264, -132, -24, 60, 120, 156, 168, 156, 120, 60, -24, -132, -264\}$,
$A=\{a,b,c\}$,
the sequence
$S=\{a,b,c,a,a,c,a,b,a,a,b,c,a\}$ is a solution of the problem. 
In fact 
$G_a = \{1,4,5,7,9,10,13\}$, $G_b = \{2,8,11\}$, $G_c = \{3,6,12\}$
$W_a = \{-264,60,120,168,120,60,-264\}$, $W_b = \{-132,156,-24\}$, $W_c = \{-24,156,-132\}$. The sum of elements inside each $W_j$ is null, $\forall j$.

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/344871/91764

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You haven't defined how you propose to measure "most similar".  Therefore, I don't think the question is objectively answerable.